# How to calculate the number of nodes in a trie, given a set of words

Tags: string, math, data-structures, trie

Wondering if there is a generic algorithm or technique for calculating how many nodes (and so, how many bytes) are in a trie.

So say there is a trie that starts off like this:

```
   a        t
   p        h
e  p        e  i
   l  s  r  i  s
   e     e  r

ape
apps
apple
the
their
there
this
```

Then imagine that there is instead a large dictionary of thousands of words. Each word consists of a set of letters `L` from an alphabet `A`. So essentially we can generate `n` number of `L`'s (words), say 100,000, of various lengths. They will overlap in certain situations, so the number of bytes it takes up in the final trie won't just be 100,000 x (avg length) sort of thing. It will instead be some fraction of the total.

I'm wondering how to calculate this. If you need to actually generate the data and then measure it, or if there is a mathematical technique for approximately modelling it quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can vary too much on the input data, so you're going to have to scan it to work out the answer. You don't actually have to construct the tries providing you can sort the input data first: given the sorted input you can just count the new letters from the last common letter on each row you scan. No need for any allocation beyond remembering the last string, and you can find the correct answer in a single scan.

Taking your example, processing the sorted list:

1. "ape" - three new letters
2. "apps" - walk back to the common 'p', then two new letters = 5 so far
3. "apple" - back to the second 'p' which is the last common letter, then two new letters = 7
4. "the" - no commonality so back to the beginning and three letters = 10
5. "their" - two new letters = 12
6. "there" - back two, two new = 14
7. "this" - back three, two new = 16

which matches your diagram which has 16 nodes.